# List view OnItemClickListener not working?

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I have a problem thats probably very simple, but i dont quite understand what i am doing wrong. I have a listview, that is loaded as a file browser. This is whats supposed to happen when I click on any of the items.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

File file = new File(path.get(position));

if (file.isDirectory())
{

if(file.canRead())
getDir(path.get(position));
else
{
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")
.setPositiveButton("OK", 
  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }
  }).show();
}

}
else
{
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)

.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)

.setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "]")

.setPositiveButton("OK", 

  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

  }).show();

}

}
```

But when i click on the items, nothing happens. I even checked the logcat to see if theres any activity when i click, but there is absolutely none. Do i need to somehow link this listener to my specific listview? Also if i need to post more information, just let me know. Thank you very much for your help!

NEW PROBLEM

```
AlertDialog show = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")
.setPositiveButton("OK", 
  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }
  }).show();
}

}
else
{
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "]")
.setPositiveButton("OK", 
  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

  }).show();

}
```

On both of these, Im getting an error that the alertDialog is undefined.

Comment: What is exact error message you get? And when? During runtime or during build? I don't see alertDialog anywhere in your code. Do you mean AlertDialog? If so, did you maybe forget to import it into your source file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to register the `ListView` with an `OnItemClickListener`

E.g. like this:

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list,
        View view, int position, long id) {
        // Your code goes here
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, i just did that, and now it actually works, could you maybe help with one more problem? The AlertDialog.Builders have an error. It says its undefined, and i tried to define it, but it doesnt quite work. Im definately missing something. Could you help with this?

Comment: i added the problem up top in the main question. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Change the context from "this" to "YourActivityName.this"

eg,
    new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivityName.this);